# Compress the image with base64 and send post from android to php

Tags: php, android, base64

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytearray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
mBitmapProfile.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytearray);
String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(bytearray.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
String data = URLEncoder.encode("SOURCE", "UTF-8") + "=" base64;

String result = getHttpData("http://example/p.php", data);


private String getHttpData(String httpUrl, String param) {
        String urlString = httpUrl;
        String data = param;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            // urlConnection.setReadTimeout(DATARETRIEVAL_TIMEOUT);

            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());

            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();

            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                String response = "";
                String line = "";
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response+=line;
                }
                return response;
            }
        } catch(MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return "";
    }
```

After base64 encoding the image

Using POST, making requests from Android to PHP will cause problems.

ex)

> android send data : /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBA+BAQEBAQE==
>
> php receive data : /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBABAQEBAQE

Some special characters are lost.

Why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that base64 encoded data can contain '+' characters. In x-www-form-urlencoded data the receiver knows that '+' is an encoding of a space character. Thus since you aren't URL encoding your base64 value, any instances of '+' will cause the data to be corrupted when received.